# Accessing from a split column

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Here is how I split a column:

```
df <- data.frame('foo' = rep(c('ab','ac'), each = 5))
df <- within(df, boo <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$foo),'',fixed=FALSE))))
```

Output:

```
   foo boo.X1 boo.X2
1   ab      a      b
2   ab      a      b
3   ab      a      b
4   ab      a      b
5   ab      a      b
6   ac      a      c
7   ac      a      c
8   ac      a      c
9   ac      a      c
10  ac      a      c
```

However, when I try to access 'boo.X1' or 'boo.X2' I cannot. For example if we look at the names() it only lists two objects 'foo' and 'boo'.

```
names(df)
# [1] "foo" "boo"
```

Maybe I am missing something obvious, any help will be appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the structure (`str`) of *df* you can see that *boo* itsself as a data.frame.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ foo: Factor w/ 2 levels "ab","ac": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
 $ boo:'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X1: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ X2: Factor w/ 2 levels "b","c": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

So you can access them by `df$boo$X1` and `df$boo$X1`

if you want to append the *boo* columns you can use `cbind` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame('foo' = rep(c('ab','ac'), each = 5))
df <- cbind(df, do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$foo),'',fixed=FALSE)))
names(df) <- c("foo", "boo_1", "boo_2")
```

which gives you

```
   foo boo_1 boo_2
1   ab     a     b
2   ab     a     b
3   ab     a     b
4   ab     a     b
5   ab     a     b
6   ac     a     c
7   ac     a     c
8   ac     a     c
9   ac     a     c
10  ac     a     c
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: They could also do `do.call(data.frame, df)` if they already had data in that structure.